# Is it possible to transfer the face of my character from one play through to a new one in TES Oblivion (PC)? If so, how?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I started playing Oblivion (on PC) recently and created the character pictured below.

I want to start a new playthrough because I am unhappy with the class I chose (created to be precise), and exited the sewer, and rewritten the save file of the sewer period. I am having trouble recreating the same face, and I want this particular face itself; which, in my opinion, looks good (by accident).

How can I transfer it?

I read about something called Wrye Bash, but could not find it. I also could not find the save game file or anything helpful in the installed directory.

[image: this character]

Comment: Do you mean you weren't able to find [Wrye Bash](https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/releases)?

Answer (score 2):

I looked around nexus mods and found [the following mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/7808/?) that I think does suit your needs. It basically lets you take certain parts of the character you like and copy them over.

Answer (score 2):

Well I can give you two options:

If you have any save BEFORE exiting the sewers you can choose another class once you get to the exit, cause the game will ask you again for your class, race and birthsign.

Or you can open the console and introduce the command showclassmenu and change your class. Be careful cause sometimes errors may occur. Hope this helps

Comment: An interesting workaround.

Comment: If you can't revert, the console is the answer all day, everyday... for everything.